# Update value in JSON using Python

Tags: python, json

I've following JSON file:

```
 {"user_list": [
        {
            "reg_no": "ABC",
            "visited_count": "1",
            "groups": [
                {
                    "group_name": "grp1"
                },
                {
                    "group_name": "grp2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

}
```

I want to update visited_count value and add group_name : grp3

Comment: Have you tried something on your own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change JSON file you can use `json` library.

```
import json

data = {}
with open('json_file.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

if len(data) == 0:
    print("no data found in file")
    return -1

data['user_list'][0]['visited_count'] = 2
data['user_list'][0]['groups'].append({'group_name':'grp3'})

with open('json_file.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(data, json_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

I mean if you have already imported that file into python, then what you wrote there is already a `dict`. So you can just do standard `dict` stuff.

```
a = {"user_list": [
    {
        "reg_no": "ABC",
        "visited_count": "1",
        "groups": [
            {
                "group_name": "grp1"
            },
            {
                "group_name": "grp2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}

a['user_list'][0]['visited_count'] = 2 # to change value
a['user_list'][0]['groups'].append({'group_name':'grp3'}) # to add key to the dict of groups

a

#{'user_list': [{'reg_no': 'ABC',
#'visited_count': 2,
#'groups': [{'group_name': 'grp1'},
#{'group_name': 'grp2'},
#{'group_name': 'grp3'}]}]}
```